# Google App Engine Launcher - localhost shows a blank page. (Python2.7)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, localhost

I'm on Win 8 x64, Python 2.7

Steps I followed:

1. Downloaded, installed python.
2. Downloaded, installed Google App Engine Launcher.
3. Created new application with name `helloworld-kg` on the app engine site.
4. In Launcher, File > Create New Application > entered the name of app and browsed to the directory.
5. Hit Run, wait for light to turn green.
6. Click Browser. Get a blank page on `localhost:8080`

Here's the log from launcher:

```
2013-04-05 20:54:10 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', u'C:\\Users\\Karan\\Desktop\\helloworld-kg\\helloworld-kg']"
INFO     2013-04-05 20:54:12,068 devappserver2.py:401] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-04-05 20:54:12,078 api_server.py:328] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-04-05 20:54:12,088 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55309
INFO     2013-04-05 20:54:12,091 dispatcher.py:98] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-04-05 20:54:12,092 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2013-04-05 20:54:58,167 api_server.py:517] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-04-05 20:54:58,167 api_server.py:520] Saving search indexes
2013-04-05 20:54:58 (Process exited with code 0)

2013-04-05 20:55:01 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', u'C:\\Users\\Karan\\Desktop\\helloworld-kg\\helloworld-kg']"
INFO     2013-04-05 20:55:03,788 devappserver2.py:401] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-04-05 20:55:03,799 api_server.py:328] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-04-05 20:55:03,809 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55354
INFO     2013-04-05 20:55:03,811 dispatcher.py:98] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-04-05 20:55:03,813 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2013-04-05 20:56:02,868 api_server.py:517] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-04-05 20:56:02,869 api_server.py:520] Saving search indexes
2013-04-05 20:56:02 (Process exited with code 0)

2013-04-05 20:56:09 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', u'C:\\Users\\Karan\\Desktop\\helloworld-kg\\helloworld-kg']"
INFO     2013-04-05 20:56:11,631 devappserver2.py:401] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-04-05 20:56:11,644 api_server.py:328] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-04-05 20:56:11,653 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55397
INFO     2013-04-05 20:56:11,655 dispatcher.py:98] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-04-05 20:56:11,657 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

My `app.yaml` file contents:

```
application: helloworld-kg
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld-kg.app
```

And the `helloworld-kg.py` file contents:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

I'm new with Python and GAE. This is for Udacity's CS 253 course.

Possible solutions?

Comment: Works for me on OS X 10.8, Python 2.7. This might be a Windows-specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Apparently, GAEL was creating a new app for me. A re-install solved the problem. App is working fine now!